# python pypdf2 pdf to text conversion

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pypdf, pdf-conversion, pymupdf

When I tried to create blank page I am getting this error new_page = PyPDF2.PageObject.create_blank_page( page_width, page_height) AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'pages'

Why this class is not working?

Comment: What are the values of page_wdth and page_height ?

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Comment: Thanks it works now. but rarely some pages are wriiten empty while I try to merge page.Why is that happening?
 page = input_pdf.pages[page_num] 
new_page = PdfReader(io.BytesIO(packet.getvalue()))
 page.merge_page(new_page.pages[0])              


page.merge_page(